# managedObjectModel Bad Instruction when show image in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift2, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm new in using swift and I have a problem to show image in my custom tableview. I take a code from [here](http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/file/uitableview_load_data_from_json_swift_2.zip)

this is my coredata

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "momd")! <---- The error in here
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

this is my code in controller

```
func extract_json(jsonData:NSData) {
        let json: AnyObject?
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
        } catch {
            json = nil
            return
        }

        if let list = json as? NSArray {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.count ; i++ ) {
                if let data_block = list[i] as? NSDictionary {
                    TableData.append(datastruct(add: data_block))
                }
            }

            do {
                try read()
            } catch {}
            do_table_refresh()
        }
    }

    func do_table_refresh() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
            //self.activityView.hidden = true
            return
        })
    }

    func load_image(urlString:String, imageview:UIImageView, index:NSInteger) {

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url) {
            (
            let location, let response, let error) in

            guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


                self.TableData[index].image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                self.save(index,image: self.TableData[index].image!)

                imageview.image = self.TableData[index].image
                return
            })


        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func read() throws {
        do {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Images")

            let fetchedResults = try managedContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

            for (var i=0; i < fetchedResults.count; i++) {
                let single_result = fetchedResults[i]
                let index = single_result.valueForKey("index") as! NSInteger
                let img: NSData? = single_result.valueForKey("image") as? NSData
                TableData[index].image = UIImage(data: img!)
            }

        } catch {
            print("error")
            throw ErrorHandler.ErrorFetchingResults
        }
    }

    func save(id:Int,image:UIImage) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Images",
            inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let options = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1)

        options.setValue(id, forKey: "index")
        options.setValue(newImageData, forKey: "image")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

in they example it run smoothly but when I try to code it in my project there is an error. It said as

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

and I can't find any way to fix it.

Please give me some hint how to fix this problem

Comment: check your coredata, maybe some mistake in image name in coredata

Comment: @Mr.Bond I take the code from the example that I mention above and I try in their example its work without any error but in my project there is an error so I think there is no mistake in image name. If there is a mistake how to check it ? sorry I'm new in using swift

Comment: add breakpoint and check in which data do you get error. one by one data check in your app(tableview delegate method)

Comment: If the error occurs when `managedObjectModel` is going to be created than there is no item `test.momd` in the application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for all the help

I have found my own solution for my problem
The solution is that CoreData I create is `xcdatamodel` not `xcdatamodeld` and in my AppDelegate I use `momd` so I just create a datamodel with `xcdatamodeld` extension